# Combining Contextual ActionBar with ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview, contextual-action-bar

Due to the android UI guidelines I've tried to implement a contextual `ActionBar` for a custom `ExpandableListView` which is implemented inside a `SherlockFragment`. I couldn't find a solution to get this running.

The last tutorial I used was [this one](http://www.miximum.fr/tutos/849-porting-the-contextual-anction-mode-for-pre-honeycomb-android-apps), but it didn't work with the expandable version of the `ListView`.

Is there a way to get this combination working?

That's the code for the SherlockFragment:

```
public class ResultFragment extends SherlockFragment implements OnGroupClickListener {

    private ExpandableListView mExpandableListView;
    private ResultExpandableAdapter mResultExpandableAdapter;

    private ActionMode mActionMode;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_result, container,   false);

        mResultExpandableAdapter = new ResultExpandableAdapter(getSherlockActivity());

        mExpandableListView = (ExpandableListView) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_result_expandableListView);
        mExpandableListView.setAdapter(mResultExpandableAdapter);
        mExpandableListView.setChoiceMode(ExpandableListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        mExpandableListView.setOnGroupClickListener(this);

        return fragmentView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

        inflater.inflate(R.menu.result_fragment, menu);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {

        SparseBooleanArray checked = mExpandableListView.getCheckedItemPositions();

        boolean hasCheckedElement = false;

        for (int i = 0 ; i < checked.size() && ! hasCheckedElement; ++i) {
            hasCheckedElement = checked.valueAt(i);
        }

        if (hasCheckedElement) {
            if (mActionMode == null) {
                mActionMode = getSherlockActivity().startActionMode(new ModeCallback());
            }
        } else {
            if (mActionMode != null) {
                mActionMode.finish();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private final class ModeCallback implements ActionMode.Callback {
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.result_fragment_context, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mResultExpandableAdapter.getGroupCount(); ++i) {
                mExpandableListView.setItemChecked(i, false);
            }
            if (mode == mActionMode) {
                mActionMode = null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            long[] selected = mExpandableListView.getCheckedItemIds();
            if (selected.length > 0) {
                for (long id: selected) {
                    // Do something with the selected item
                }
            }
            mode.finish();
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: *it didn't work with the expandable version of the ListView.* - and what happened?

Comment: Nothing. No reaction when pressing (long) on the parent/group.

Comment: First of all, I don't see anywhere in your code where you set the fragment as the listener for the `ExpandableListView`. Secondly, an `ExpandableListView` has two types of listeners(for events on groups and events on children) and you should use those.

Comment: I accidentally deleted the set-listener method when I prepared the code for the post. It didn't work anyway. I changed the listener to the onGroupClickListener, but I still don't get a contextual action mode/bar